# Getting count to work with Grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have an InfluxDB query that works:

`select count("cars") from "bridge_activity" where time > now() - 1m group by count`

When I enter this query into Grafana on a dashboard, nothing shows up.  I've been sure to zoom out enough that the time period in question is visible.

What I'm trying to do is, keep track of the number of cars that have gone over the bridge, over the past minute.  I'd like to use this as a measurement of relative activity for the bridge.

What am I doing wrong on the Grafana dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `group by count` if you just want a value for a singlestat panel.

If you're looking to graph the number of cars over time, then you need a query like `SELECT count("cars") from "bridge_activity" GROUP BY time(1m)`

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals

Comment: I was hoping to have a graph (a bar every 'x' seconds or minute, for example) that would be sort of a rolling 'count last minute'

Comment: Updated the answer